# Batch script to rename folder to a new name and increment new name

Tags: batch-file, directory, increment

I'm a novice at batch sripting. I've been using Robocopy in a batch file (that calls a PowerShell script) to do various tasks that have made work life much more efficient. Now I need to rename a folder with a different name and increment that different name by 1 for each time the batch script is executed. Spacing is important because I have software that will not read the path if it is underscored between the naming.

C:\Users\Desktop\Source\

What exists in this path is a folder sequence like this:

Folders Now
  Folders Now Previous 1
  Folders Now Previous 2

I've been trying to find a batch script that will rename *Folders Now* to *Folders Now Previous 'next increment'*, but I've had no luck. I've tried various scripts that I've found and they work to a certain degree, but none of them do exactly this. Spacing between the naming is important (there can't be Folders_Now_Previous_3), and that's where the other scripts fail.

I've been using a batch script that will look at the highest last number and increment that name by 1. That works, but the naming parameter (source name and new name) aka *set "baseName=*  are the same and they need to be different, and it also involves underscores and that's a no-go for the legacy software.

EDIT:
I've been using this script from an older post in this forum:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "baseName=Folders_Now_Previous_"
    set "n=0"
    for /f "delims=" %%F in (
      '2^>nul dir /b /ad "%baseName%*."^|findstr /xri "%baseName%[0-9]*"'
    ) do (
      set "name=%%F"
      set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
      if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
    )
    set /a n+=1
    md "%baseName%%n%"
```

When this script is executed, it returns this:

Folders_Now_Previous_1
  Folders_Now_Previous_2
  Folders_Now_Previous_3

What I've been trying to do is modify it so that the output doesn't contain underscores. It should output this:

Folders Now Previous 1
  Folders Now Previous 2
  Folders Now Previous 3

My attempts at modifying it will work the first time but it will stop working after the first folder is renamed.

Comment: You really need to search this site, this is a very common request with both files and directories. Please try harder because we're not a script request service, we only help you to fix specific issues with your code. I'd suggest that you take a look at [ask], after taking the [tour], but before writing some code yourself.

Comment: Try to learn the basics of python scripting language, use an editor like Komodo edit or Jupyter notebook... then you can knock yourself out on all fancy things you can imagine.. like renaming folders with your fingers in nose... Also poste a few things you treid after the Ctrl-F on SO as suggested by Compo.

Comment: Instead of revising the original post, should I just add to this one or create a new one? Also, @ZF007 thanks for the recommendations. I'll look into those editors.

Comment: Apologies. I should have inserted the code I've been working with for this issue. I did a search on this forum prior to posting but nothing was this specific. I was able to come up with a solution for one my issues last night. Now I've been trying to remove the underscores from the newly created folder names and when I do, the increments stop working and it will only create the first folder.

Comment: No worries. Just update your question by pasting in the code under bullet "my code" or "script" and then the partial solution and accompanied output under for example "edit 1" or "update 1". This makes it obvious you improved and still didn't fix it to get the preferred result. It is important to have your script/code in the question (one of the requirements to post questions on SO) because others then can see and help you much faster.